# NordVPN not working on Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, aur

I can't make NordVPN work on Manjaro.

I git cloned [the repo](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nordvpn-bin/), run makepkg -d in order to build it and resolve dependencies and then run

```
sudo pacman -U nordvpn-bin-3.3.1_3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

But trying to execute any nordvpn-related command (login, connect, etc.) results in an error

```
Whoops! Cannot reach User Daemon
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As shown in Manjaro Forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-nordvpn-usage-installation-and-updating/71268), after installing the nordvpn package, it is needed to enable/start the service daemon to use it, by executing:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now nordvpnd
```

Thus solving this issue